# hive and unix scripting

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive

I have a **csv file and a CTL** with file information like column names,size,rowcount,location

I have to load that to **hive** and create a ctl file for the hive table

and **check if both the ctl file matches or not**

I am thinking to write a **bash script**  to extract  hive table information from hive command  **'describe formatted tablename'** and creating another ctl file and compare both CTl file .

not sure about scripting syntax but I think it can be acheieved

is there another way of getting hive table information ?or another way for the whole approach

Comment: Just FYI, you can get the output of describe formatted tablename using hive -e command. You can integrate that with the script.

Comment: that's what I am trying .but I want scripting info about it and I want to extract more information from hive  table and extract in a single line .below is my Sample CTL file for csv file .  FILE_NAME|FILE_SIZE|ROW_COUNT|FILE_CREATED|COL1|COL2|COL3|..COLN|

Comment: I want to extract only column name from the describe formatted command.any help on the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get column names only

```
hive -e "describe <table_name>"|awk -F" " '{ print $1 }'
```

If you want to redirect to a file

```
hive -e "describe <table_name>"|awk -F" " '{ print $1 }' >> describe.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

1) provide the complete information about the CTL file.
2) parse the ctl file of csv and create a hive table A based on that
3) using the same parser create table B with the other ctl table
4) run 'describe formatted table A and table B by removing entries like CreateTime: LastAccessTime Location and put it in a file
5) find difference of each file

probably if you can give more details on how the files are by example we can prepare bash scripts to automate it.

provide the desc table name output here to give you the bash script to get column names